# User mapped to a certificate in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-administration, sql-server-2012-express

I need to create a user ,who can log on to a contained  DB.In this context what is the benifit of using a user mapped to a certificate?

Comment: Have anybody used this facility in SQL?Please share

Comment: You'll probably get a better response if you ask this question at http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks young..I do not know which stupid person has maked a negative on my question!

Comment: I can not understand y some ppl are marking negative for my question?As if they know everything...I am sure the person ,who has marked a negative even do not heard about a contained database